# JSON API + Jquery to display current hours

Tags: jquery, json

I want to display the current hours for three branches of a library. We have a management system that houses the hours but I can't get it to enumerate for each library. I just get the first one repeated three times.

Here is the jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https...",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (results) {
            var libHours = results.locations[0].times.status;
            var library = results.locations[0].name;
            var hours = results.locations[0].rendered;
            $(results.locations).each(function (index, value) {
                $('#libHoursAll').append('<li>' + library + ': ' + hours + '</li>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

I'm new at this, but what am I doing wrong? The html at the moment is just a div with id="libHoursAll" Here is a sample of  the JQuery it is calling: Sorry about the confusion. edited to add the entire array, properly copied and pasted.

```
{
    "locations": [{
        "lid": 106,
        "name": "University Library",
        "category": "library",
        "day": "Monday",
        "times": {
            "currently_open": true,
            "status": "open",
            "hours": [{
                "from": "9am",
                "to": "4pm"
            }]
        },
        "rendered": "9am - 4pm"
    }, {
        "lid": 107,
        "name": "Library 2",
        "category": "library",
        "day": "Monday",
        "times": {
            "currently_open": false,
            "note": "Christmas Break",
            "status": "closed"
        },
        "rendered": "Closed Christmas Break"
    }, {
        "lid": 108,
        "name": "Library 3",
        "category": "library",
        "day": "Monday",
        "color": "#DD6535",
        "times": {
            "currently_open": false,
            "status": "open",
            "hours": [{
                "from": "10am",
                "to": "4pm"
            }]
        },
        "rendered": "10am - 4pm"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Whoops - edited to add json -  forgot to include a pertinent part of the Json"rendered" bit

Comment: There are several syntax errors in your JSON - `"times"` is not closed, `"hours"` is not closed, and the JSON object itself isn't closed.  You're also missing a comma.

Comment: As it's currently written, hours is closed but it's missing a comma after to:4pm

Comment: I can't really help the json - it's coming from a vendor but I'll pass it on. Also - I think it's right, I just didn't grab the end when I copied and pasted.

Comment: His point is you did not show all the JSON so we must make some assumptions about it. See my answer below, as I've gotten it working in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Xorat/8a64tpmc/

Comment: @BotsyD - I've made an edit to the JSON to make it syntactically (and logically) correct.  Please review it, and if that's not how it's supposed to look, please correct it - or just rollback the edit.  Thanks.

Comment: Much better!  Thanks @BotsyD!  Now that we've ruled out syntax errors, I can work on giving you a detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I've assigned the JSON to a simple variable `results` to mimic what you have coming in from your AJAX call.

```js
var results = {
    "locations": [{
        "lid": 106,
        "name": "University Library",
        "category": "library",
        "day": "Monday",
        "times": {
            "currently_open": true,
            "status": "open",
            "hours": [{
                "from": "9am",
                "to": "4pm"
            }]
        },
        "rendered": "9am - 4pm"
    }, {
        "lid": 107,
        "name": "Library 2",
        "category": "library",
        "day": "Monday",
        "times": {
            "currently_open": false,
            "note": "Christmas Break",
            "status": "closed"
        },
        "rendered": "Closed Christmas Break"
    }, {
        "lid": 108,
        "name": "Library 3",
        "category": "library",
        "day": "Monday",
        "color": "#DD6535",
        "times": {
            "currently_open": false,
            "status": "open",
            "hours": [{
                "from": "10am",
                "to": "4pm"
            }]
        },
        "rendered": "10am - 4pm"
    }]
}


// This would go in your "success" function from the AJAX call
for (var i = 0; i < results.locations.length; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = results.locations[i].name + ": " + results.locations[i].rendered
    document.body.appendChild(p);
}
```

All I do is iterate over the `locations` array of the JSON, then pull in the `name` and `rendered` objects into a `p` element, then insert that element into the body.

Let me know if you need any further assistance.

Comment: Awesome! I figured out how to modify the code you have me to put it in a list instead of paragraph tags, but what if I need to append it to a specific id?

Comment: Good to hear!  If you need to append it to a specific element, use `document.getElementById("specificElementId").appendChild(newNode)`

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the array, but then you're referencing only the first item in that array in these lines:

```
 var libHours = results.locations[0].times.status;
 var library = results.locations[0].name;
 var hours = results.locations[0].rendered;
```

Change the following code like so:

```
$(results.locations).each(function(index,value) { 
    $('#libHoursAll').append('<li>'+ value.name + ': '+ value.rendered +'</li>');
});
```

Note: For `value.hours.rendered`, I don't see `rendered` shown in your example JSON, so you may need to use whatever property you see fit.

Comment: I tried removing the [0] already, which results in no returns with or without value.library/hours. If I leave the zeroes and add value.hours, I get undefined.

Comment: updated the answer to use value.name and value.hours.rendered

Answer (score 0):

I use [jsonmate.com](http://jsonmate.com/) to visualize json objects. Check out part of your object here - http://www.jsonmate.com/permalink/54988b1e8622dbdf0c4230b5. Scroll down a bit and expand the objects with the + sign.

It looks to me like hours is an array, so maybe you need to get the info like this:

```
locations[0].times.hours[0].from
locations[0].times.hours[0].to
locations[0].times.hours[0].rendered
```

Finally, to get three different libraries, run a for loop and use the index instead of zero every time. Switching the 0 to 1, 2, 3, etc will give you the data for each library.

Given a few assumptions about your JSON structure at the time of this writing, I have it working in this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/Xorat/8a64tpmc/